# [sys.argv[0]] meaning in python

Tags: python, email

i was checking with a python script to send email with attachment and came across a code line as

```
attachments = [sys.argv[0]]
```

So i don't understand if i have to pass my attachment path variable through this OR how it takes attachment file path by itself OR what does it meant for in below code snippet.

```
email = Email(from_='"%s" <%s>' % (name, email), #you can pass only email
          to='"%s" <%s>' % (to_name, to_email), #you can pass only email
          subject=subject, message=message, attachments=attachments)
```

so how/where to pass my attachment file(path) to above code.

Please explain. or can anybody give me an example by which i can send email with message body and with attachment to multiple email ids also.

Answer (score 3):

Add the attachment file name to the command where you execute the python file:

```
python myfile.py attachment_file.txt
```

`sys.argv[1]` gets the first command line argument.

Comment: ASwin, should i add just attachment_file.txt or full file path name

Comment: @Aswin ... isn't that the first argument of that command line is `myfile.py` and actually should be in the code `attachments = [sys.argv[1]]` ?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور: Yeah 1. Sorry. 0 is used in Java :P

Comment: @Satya: The entire path to the attachment file

Answer (score 3):

Your code is suggesting that the first filename passed by user as command line argument will be send as attachement along with mail. Thus

you must use

```
attachments = [sys.argv[1]]
```

instead of

```
attachments = [sys.argv[0]]
```

attachement argument in Email() expects a list of filenames and your script is configured to send only one file as attachement. You can make it to send more than one files using

```
attachments = sys.argv[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change in your code this line:

`attachments = [sys.argv[0]]` to `attachments = [sys.argv[1]]`, it should work for you, as the first argument in the command line (`argv[0]`) is the name of the file script (`myfile.py` for example)

As for the path of the attachment, id the attachment file is in the same folder as your script file (`myfile.py`) then only the name of the attachment file will be enough otherwise you need to provide the complete path to your attachment file.

Comment: if you have time can you please give me an code example by which i can send email with message BODY(in mimemultipart or by any prefered way) and with attachment to MULTIPLE email ids also...it will be very helpful for me as a beginner.Thanks.